# similarTrees in java

Tags: java, abstract-data-type

This is what I have to do. The Binary Search Tree ADT is extended to include a bool ean method si m i l ar Trees that receives references to two binary trees and determines whether the shapes of the trees are the same. (The nodes do not have to contain the same values, but each node must have the same number of children.) I have code to show what I have.

```
public static <T> boolean  similarTrees(BSTNode<T> a, BSTNode<T> b) {
    // check for reference equality and nulls
    if (a == b) return true; // note this picks up case of two nulls
    if (a == null) return false;
    if (b == null) return false;

    // check for data inequality
    if (a.data != b.data) {
        if ((a.data == null) || (b.data == null)) return false;
        if (!(a.data.equals(b.data))) return false;
    }

    // recursively check branches
    if (!similarTrees(a.left, b.left)) return false;
    if (!similarTrees(a.right, b.right)) return false;

    // we've eliminated all possibilities for non-equality, so trees must be equal
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is this the right syntax because its not working

Comment: What is the problem with this code? Compile error? Does it not do what you expect? In the latter case, tell us your testcase, what you expect, and what happened.

Comment: Bound Mismatch,data can not be revolved or is it not a field, .left and .right is not visible. These are the errors am getting

Comment: change to `getLeft()`, `getRight()` and `getData()` - most likely. It's not clear which library you're using though so don't know the implementation of your BSTNode  class.

Comment: Now im getting this that saids: Can not make a static reference to non-static type T

Comment: Also there is no getData() in the BSTNode class

Comment: That's great. As long as you don't tell use what BSTNode class you're using, there's no way anyone can help. And why did you think you could use `left`, `right` and `data` fields in the first place? Did you find that in some documentation?

Comment: Ya I look it up